# Writing a script to remove formulae in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet of data that reads in information from another sheet throughout the day via a vlookup. The other sheet is linked to a website via an importxml which refreshed throughout the day.

Once the information has been obtained, i need to remove the formula and leave the values in place. I.e. Once the cell no longer reads as #N/A, replace that row of data with values. My idea is then to set this as a trigger to then run every hour, looping through each row and updating all the rows that no longer show #N/A.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace the output of a formula with static values by running the following script. The key point is that a certain range is [copied to itself, but only as values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)).

```
function freezeValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  // or whatever name
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z1");    // assuming your data appears in A1-Z1 
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

That said, it'd be more logical to keep the formula in place, so it continues to produce the output you wish to log, and instead copy its output elsewhere, for example to a new row of the spreadsheet. Example:

```
function logValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  // or whatever name
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z1");    // assuming your data appears in A1-Z1 
  var values = range.getValues();         // get the data
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);   // appends a row with these values to the bottom of sheet
}
```

Comment: zaq. This is a great start so thank you but i need to take it a step further. I have roughly 100 lines per day. The 'results' for these lines will update throughout the day so at 9:00 lines 3,5,17,25 might update, then at 9:30 the results for lines 7, 35, 40, 92 may be added and then more and more throughout the day via an importxml. Basically, every time the importxml refreshes the whole sheet then recalculates which takles a fair amount of time, and obvioulsy all the results 'reset' during that period as the importxml 'blanks' out and then refreshes.

Comment: Therefore...the final part of the 'puzzle' is a simple vlookup on the sheet in question, which shows as #N/A until the results comes in. I want to the loop to run every hour and perform the code essentially as above but on a line by line basis for all the rows that already have their result and therefore no longer show as #N/A. Hope that's clear. Again Thanks for your help already and if you can add anything further it would be hugely appreciated. Kind regards.

Comment: None of you ever showed how to remove a formula from a cell????? clear() does not clearContent() does not